# CS7036 C# in Array.FindAll + Lambda

Tags: c#

I want to change A to B.
A is

```
int[] list = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

List<int> evenList = new List<int>();
foreach ( var item in list )
{
  if (item % 2 == 0)
  {
    evenList.Add(item);
  }
}

foreach ( var item in evenList )
{
  Console.Write(item + ",");
}
```

and B is

```
List<int> evenList = list.FindAll((elem) => elem % 2 == 0);
evenList.ForEach(elem) => { Console.Write(elem + ","); } );
```

but at B, I faced an Error like this:

```
CS7036  C# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required
formal parameter 'match' of 'Array.FindAll<T>(T[], Predicate<T>)'
```

ps. I added using

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Is there anything that I forgot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int[] list = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

List<int> evenList = Array.FindAll(list, elem => elem % 2 == 0).ToList();

evenList.ForEach(elem => { Console.Write(elem + ","); } );
```

1. `Array.FindAll` is not extension method, so you simply can't call list.FindAll()
2. `Array` do not have ForEach, so you need to cast evenList `ToList()`

Answer (score 2):

That's because `Array.FindAll` is static, so you should call it like this:

```
var NewList = Array.FindAll(list, (elem) => elem %2 == 0);
```

From MSDN:

```
Syntax:
public static T[] FindAll<T>(
    T[] array,
    Predicate<T> match
)
```

link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kkxfxdd(v=vs.110).aspx

Cheers

EDIT:

Programming is not a guessing game where you try to write code without respecting the proper syntax.

Here's what you should be doing:

```
        int[] list = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        List<int> evenList = Array.FindAll(list, elem => elem % 2 == 0).ToList();
        Console.Write(string.Join(",", evenList) );
```

Comment: that's not working TT
The other Errors occur:
`CS0411  C# The type arguments for method 'Array.FindAll<T>(T[], Predicate<T>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`
and at ForEach,
`CS7036  C# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter '' of 'Array.ForEach<T>(T[], Action<T>)'`

Comment: Please do read the reference material. There is even a code example.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you aren't using Linq? It is newer and applies to any type of collection, not just `int[]`.

```
using System.Linq;

Console.Write(list
    .Where(i => i % 2 == 0)
    .Select(i => i.ToString())
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
    .Aggregate((a, b) => a + "," + b));
```

Performancewise, this will execute at the same complexity as your for loop, but it will likely be slightly slower overall (though I actually think it won't be that much slower). Linq evaluates lazily which helps here.